# Nginx redirect old urls from drupal

Tags: nginx

I moved from drupal to jekyll using nginx as webserver

I've got old urls prefixed with `/?q=permalink`

I'me trying to rewrite them but it fails, and I don't understand why.

example :

`http://my.domain.net/?q=my-post-permalink`

has to be redirected to

`http://my.domain.net/my-post-permalink`

my default.conf :

```
location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    rewrite ^/\?q=(.*)$ $1 break;
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404; 
}
```

logs :

```
2018/01/14 09:42:17 [notice] 5#5: *1 "^/\?q=(.*)$" does not match "/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /?q=my-post-permalink HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.net"
2018/01/14 09:42:17 [notice] 5#5: *1 "^/\?q=(.*)$" does not match "/index.html", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /?q=my-post-permalink HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.net"
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2018:09:42:17 +0000] "GET /?q=my-post-permalink HTTP/1.1" 200 3520 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" "-"
2018/01/14 09:42:17 [notice] 5#5: *1 "^/\?q=(.*)$" does not match "/css/foundation.css", client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /css/foundation.css HTTP/1.1", host: "my.domain.net", referrer: "http://my.domain.net/?q=my-post-permalink"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rewrite` directive uses a normalised URI that is stripped of the query string. The query string can be accessed using the `$arg_` family of variables. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) for more.

You are only interested in rewriting the `q` parameter of the `/` URI, so an exact match location block should be used. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

For example:

```
root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
index  index.html index.htm;

location = / {
    if ($arg_q) {
        return 301 /$arg_q;
    }
}

location / {
    try_files ...;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

Comment: Great, it works. But I wrote the if ($arg)... juste after the try directive inside the same location block.

Comment: If you place it inside the `location /` block, it will redirect URIs like `/foo?q=bar` as well as `/?q=bar`. If that is what you require.